Is there a formal logical structure to natural language?
Is there a formal logical structure to natural language?
I ask because of the following: Let C signify cats.
Let D signify dogs.
Let M signify mammals.
Let → signify is or are.
Let ∀(C→M) translate to all cats are mammals.
Let ∀(D→M) translate to all dogs are mammals.
Then we have ∀(C→M)∧∀(D→M)|=∀(C∧D→M), where ∀(C∧D→M) translates to all cats and dogs are mammals.
We could also have the following too: ∀(C→M)∧∀(D→M)|=∀((C∨D)→M), where ∀((C∨D)→M) translates to all dogs or cats are mammals.
We could also have the following too: ∃(C→M) translates to some cats are mammals. ∃(D→M) translates to some dogs are mammals. Thus, we would have ∃(C→M)∧∃(D→M)|=∃(C∧D→M), where ∃(C∧D→M) translates to some cats and dogs are mammals.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You ask:

Is there a formal logical structure to natural language?

Natural language is usually held in contrast to artificial, formal languages, so a natural language has a logical structure, but a formalism that is designed to abstract that logical structure from the natural language necessarily omits some of the information that the natural language contains. In this light, one can view the formal language as the object language and the natural language grounding of that formalism as an metalanguage. From WP:

In logic and linguistics, a metalanguage is a language used to describe another language, often called the object language.1 Expressions in a metalanguage are often distinguished from those in the object language by the use of italics, quotation marks, or writing on a separate line.[citation needed] The structure of sentences and phrases in a metalanguage can be described by a metasyntax.

Thus, when we discuss FOL in a book, the FOL is often written in a distinct type face to emphasize switching back between the meta- and object-level text.
While Frege's formalization of logic within his project of logicism is considered the start of such a project to formalize, it is not the end. Other contributors to that process include Tarski, Chomsky, Montague, and Partee. Barbara Partee in fact studied under Chomsky and worked with Montague and has been instrumental in disseminating linguistic formal semantics. From WP:

Formal semantics is the study of grammatical meaning in natural languages using formal concepts from logic, mathematics and theoretical computer science. It is an interdisciplinary field, sometimes regarded as a subfield of both linguistics and philosophy of language. It provides accounts of what linguistic expressions mean and how their meanings are composed from the meanings of their parts. The enterprise of formal semantics can be thought of as that of reverse-engineering the semantic components of natural languages' grammars.

As formalizing natural language rests on various techniques and philosophies, there is no one "right-way" to do it, which is another way to say that the details might be contentious. In addition there's a lot that still isn't understood. McCawley, for instance, surveyed The Syntactic Phenomena of English, but doesn't consider his 2-volume work complete a "right" way of doing formalisms. This sort of debate over formalisms and what they mean is shared by logicians, linguists, and philosophers.
It's important to remember that there are a lot of different formal grammars and approaches to formalizing grammar. Chomsky's current approach is called the minimalist program. Logicians champion various forms of FOL. How one moves from natural language to formalisms is a concern to philosophers of linguistics (SEP).
But ultimately, the process is empirical because natural language contains a lot of information in a very compact way as a context-sensitive grammar. Thus, logical notations grow in leaps in bounds when features are considered. For instance, one can take a look at the phenomenon of generic generalizations (SEP) and attempt to formalize the logic. Since these formalizations are conventions, they are normative in that they are built with a shared understanding.
You say:

Let → signify is or are.

But this is usually used for a conditional statement. There's no reason you can't do it, however it might create problems. When you repurpose create an idiosyncratic notation using symbols that already have conventions, you will likely cause confusion.

∀x∈Cats ( x∈Mammals ).
≡ Every cat is a mammal.
∀x∈Cats⋃Dogs ( x∈Mammals ).
≡ Every cat or dog is a mammal.
≡ All cats and dogs are mammals.
HasSomeOf(Cart,Eggs) ∨ HasSomeOf(Cart,Milk) ⇒ Complete(Cart).
≡ If the cart contains eggs or milk, then the cart is complete.
HasSomeOf(Cart,Eggs) ∧ HasSomeOf(Cart,Milk) ⇒ Complete(Cart).
≡ If the cart contains eggs and milk, then the cart is complete.
The reason that "or" and "and" appear to behave the same way for "cat or dog" but not "contains eggs or milk" is that "or" does not merely function as a logical disjunction in English; it joins at the highest possible level, stopping typically at a quantifier or modal boundary.
In "every cat or dog" it joins two nouns "cat" and "dog", functioning as union in the same way as "and". In "contains eggs or milk" it functions as logical disjunction, and the phrase expands to "the cart contains eggs or the cart contains milk".
To check that it typically stops at the modal boundary created by "if", consider the following:
¬HasSomeOf(Cart,Eggs) ∧ ¬HasSomeOf(Cart,Milk) ⇒ ¬Complete(Cart).
≡ If the cart does not contain eggs and milk, then the cart is incomplete.
¬HasSomeOf(Cart,Eggs) ∨ ¬HasSomeOf(Cart,Milk) ⇒ ¬Complete(Cart).
≡ If the cart does not contain eggs or milk, then the cart is incomplete.
These are the typical interpretations, but some people may misinterpret if their "and" or "or" stops at the negation boundary.

This is a rather bizarre notation. If you want to say that all dogs are mammals, you can use set notation: D⊂M. If you mean that the concept of a dog includes the concept of being a mammal you could use an alternate operator such as M⊏D. What is the point of using a distributed notation where you need two symbols to express one relation? If you want to express that some dogs are mammals, this is the same as saying that the intersection of the two is non-empty: D∩M≠∅. You could invent an operator for this relationship, say D↑M.
Leibnitz explored these notions long ago. You might want to check his Axiomatization of the Theory of the Syllogism and his Algebra of Concepts.
However, this isn't all you need to handle the logical structure of language because this only handles properties. You also need to handle relations such as Able is the father of Baker. You can't use simple binary relations to deal with such things, you need something with the power of bound variables.
